# Question about rails, partials and view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, popup

Excuse me, There is a Rails way for:

When I load a partial: load a particular action (action on action)
Example The program is on new action. This load a partial so while load this partial load a other action or code.

OR

I don´t find a tutorial about popup with ajax. I try facebox and robinator but i need a popup that charge his content through request to server.

I need some as popup in stackoverflow or facebook which charge his info dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example3/index.html` there is an AJAX example.

Answer (score 1):

The colorpowered is a nice solution that uses query. For a prototype based solution try:
http://livepipe.net/, it provides nice windows/popups/modals functionality.